# Is list-style-image (effectively) a deprecated style?

Tags: css, list

I recently tried to make a `list-style-image` line up with its list item text, only to discover that it's essentially impossible, and that everyone recommends using `background-image` instead.

This led me to wonder: is there even any reason for this style to exist anymore, since everyone seems to use `background-image` instead?  Is there anything you can do with `list-style-image` that can't be done any other way (or can be done more easily)?  Or is the tag, for all intents and purposes, deprecated now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears there is no valid use case for `list-style-image`.  While there are several workarounds to get a similar effect (`background-image` or `::before`/`::after` images), none of them actually use `list-style-image`, and they all are superior (eg. they give more control) to `list-style-image`.

There is also a CSS Working Group proposal for `::marker` which  might, someday, if it's ever actually approved, make `list-style-image` have a reason to exist again.

But for now there is no reason (or at least no reason given in an answer here) why any developer should ever use `list-style-image`.  While it's not technically deprecated, for all intents and purposes it appears to be effectively deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not deprecated. But good layout control of it depends on browsers implementing the `::marker` pseudo element, which it seems, is still a fair way off.

See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#markers

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is use `before pseudo` like the following:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Sunglasses_Emoji_be26cc0a-eef9-49e5-8da2-169bb417cc0b_large.png?v=1480481057);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>green</li>
  <li>yellow</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Right, `::before` is another totally viable option to `background-image`.  But this still doesn't answer my question: is `list-style-type` purely junk from CSS's early days, or is there (still) a reason for the style to exist?